# AVG on more than one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that in one column saved grade of a course and in another column save the ratio of that course, then I want to calculate average of courses with ratio, I write these code but I faces with error, please help me

```
select SUM((grade * ratio) / SUM(ratio)) as averageOfCourses
from myTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably misplaced parentheses.

```
SELECT SUM(grade * ratio) / SUM(ratio) AS averageOfCourses
  FROM myTable
```

If you truly want to do a SUM of the values divided by a SUM, then you have to work a good deal harder; you can't do aggregates of aggregates directly.

To do what you wrote, you'd have to rewrite it as:

```
SELECT SUM((grade * ratio) / sum_ratio) AS averageOfCourses
  FROM (SELECT grade, ratio, SUM(ratio) AS sum_ratio
          FROM myTable
         GROUP BY grade, ratio) AS precalculation
```

(The final `AS` is required by standard SQL, but doesn't contribute anything to this query.)

In this context, I'm not even sure it gives a different answer.

Comment: Yes, It is... What the funny problem? thanks a lot I was thinking on it for 30 minutes :D

Answer (score 2):

try

```
select (SUM(grade * ratio) / SUM(ratio)) as averageOfCourses from myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @sum float = (select sum(ratio) from myTable)
select sum( grade * ratio / @sum ) as averageOfCourses from myTable
```

Comment: This works but the dual operation is not actually necessary and might even be slightly less efficient than a single statement.

Comment: I just ran all the queries to see the execution plan and results.  SELECT SUM(grade * ratio) / SUM(ratio) gives the same result and execution plan as my query.  Your alternate query gives different results and takes 4x as long to execute.